# Postgres connection logged temp file, but no query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, logs

I'm going over some logs for a Postgres database and came across the following logs and I'm at a loss as to what would've caused it.

```
connection authorized: user=app1 database=pg SSL enabled (protocol=TLSv1.3, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression=off)
disconnection: session time: 0:00:01.214 user=app1 database=pg host=X.X.X.X port=5678
temporary file: path "/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp2245181.0", size 55435264
```

The above sequence repeats 3 times, but there are no other logs for the app (ie no queries logged). What would cause a temp file to be created that is so large, when no query is logged?

Did the app close the port before the query completed?

If so, could data have started streaming to the client before the connection was closed?

Comment: Make sure that `log_min_error_statement` is set to `log` or lower.

Comment: Fix your log_line_prefix to include (at least) time and pid.